# How to only pull a row once from MS Query

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, ms-query

So I have a "Sample", "Test" and "Result" table linked to each other from a database and I am trying to pull information using MS Query. Each sample has one test and each test could have roughly 20 results entered by different people attached to it.

What I want is for the sample to only display if the person's name I enter is NOT involved with entering ANY of the results.

```
SELECT SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NUMBER, SAMPLE.TEXT_ID, SAMPLE.STATUS, SAMPLE.DATE_COMPLETED, SAMPLE.LOCATION, TEST.ANALYSIS, RESULT.ENTERED_BY

FROM DATABASE.RESULT RESULT, DATABASE.SAMPLE SAMPLE, DATABASE.TEST TEST

WHERE TEST.SAMPLE_NUMBER = SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NUMBER AND RESULT.TEST_NUMBER = TEST.TEST_NUMBER 
        AND ((TEST.ANALYSIS='ID_META' Or TEST.ANALYSIS='ID_RIBO' Or TEST.ANALYSIS='ID_BACTERIA' Or TEST.ANALYSIS='ID_MOULD') 
        AND (SAMPLE.STATUS='C') AND (SAMPLE.DATE_COMPLETED Is Not Null) 
        AND (RESULT.ENTERED_ON Between [Start Date] And [End Date]) 
        AND (RESULT.ENTERED_BY<>[Enter Name]))
ORDER BY SAMPLE.DATE_COMPLETED
```

This is the code that I have so far but the problem is if Alan has entered one of 10 results then that same sample will display 9 times and just not display for the one time he didn't enter a result. Is there a way that I can say if he entered ANY result at all then the sample won't appear at all.

Edit - To include additional clauses incorporated into the query. Query pulled directly from Excel connection window (from MS Query).

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to be describing `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT s.SAMPLE_NUMBER
FROM DATABASE.SAMPLE s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM DATABASE.RESULT r JOIN
                       DATABASE.TEST t
                       ON r.TEST_NUMBER = t.TEST_NUMBER
                  WHERE t.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s.SAMPLE_NUMBER AND 
                        R.ENTERED_ON >= DATE '2020-02-01' AND
                        R.ENTERED_ON >= DATE '2020-02-03' AND
                        R.ENTERED_BY = 'ALAN'
                 ) AND  
      S..DATE_COMPLETED Is Not Null ;
```

I have left in your additional conditions, even though they are not mentioned in the question.

Notes:

- *NEVER* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Use proper `DATE` constants in Oracle.
- Don't use `BETWEEN` with `DATE` *particularly* in Oracle.  The `DATE` datatype has a time component, which might not be visible when you look at the data.

Comment: Hey, can you look at the updated query above with added clauses and how to incorporate them? I looked at your code and my only comments are: s, t and r don't work, I have to write the full word while in MS Query. Also is the syntax for both dates meant to be >=

As for your notes: Is there a particular reason not to use commas, as MS Query automatically adds them in. And for the date issue apologies for that I was using ts {} with time and date but changed it to a parameter that pulls from an excel that recognises DD-MMM-YYYY and just forgot to change it back to the original when posting.

Comment: @potterwiz . . . No.  I don't go into back-and-forth on questions.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question, not by invalidated existing answers.

Comment: I just want to state I was not trying to invalidate you answer. What I was stating was your answer posted did not work for my original statement and give an error

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NUMBER) as SAMPLE_NUMBER 
FROM DATABASE.SAMPLE SAMPLE
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATABASE.TEST TEST ON TEST.SAMPLE_NUMBER = SAMPLE.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATABASE.RESULT RESULT ON RESULT.TEST_NUMBER = TEST.TEST_NUMBER
WHERE ((SAMPLE.DATE_COMPLETED Is Not Null) 
AND (RESULT.ENTERED_ON Between CAST('01-FEB-2020' as DATE) And CAST('02-FEB-2020' as DATE))
AND (RESULT.ENTERED_BY <> 'ALAN'))
```

Comment: I have tried this but I come up with an error saying "SAMPLE"."SAMPLE_NUMBER": invalid identifier. I have double checked and there are no typos that I can see and it works in my original code fine